# Proper points() use in multiples maps with for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, points

I would like to make several maps (one for each species of my dataset), but somehow I am not able to achieve what I am looking for.

I want to plot every species record in its map, but I just create maps with a single dot in it for each one... I cannot understand what is wrong with my script. Could you help me? Thank you!

```
elevation <- getData("alt", country = "ES", mask=F)
slope <- terrain(elevation, opt = "slope",neighbors=4) 
aspect <- terrain(elevation, opt = "aspect",neighbors=4)
hill <- hillShade(slope, aspect, 40, 270)
newextent<-extent(-7.99, -2.87, 39.9, 41.5)
land.pal <- colorRampPalette(c("#336600", "#F3CA89", "#D9A627", 
                               "#A49019", "#9F7B0D", "#996600", "#B27676", "#C2B0B0", "#E5E5E5", 
                               "#FFFFFF"), space="Lab") (1000)


for (i in seq_along(data$Species)) {
  pdf(file=paste0("map ", data$Species[[i]],".pdf"), onefile=F)
  plot(disaggregate(crop(elevation,newextent), 1, method="bilinear"), col = land.pal, legend=F)  
  points(data$Lat[[i]],data$Long[[i]], col="black") ##The error must be here, but I cannot fix it
  dev.off()
}
```

Thank you in advance

Data:

```
Lat Long    Species
-6.99   40.49   Sp1
-5.05   40.60   Sp1
-3.30   40.02   Sp1
-7.51   40.86   Sp1
-3.18   40.24   Sp1
-3.83   40.08   Sp1
-7.28   40.91   Sp1
-7.74   40.53   Sp1
-7.72   40.69   Sp1
-4.36   40.06   Sp1
-5.90   40.51   Sp2
-5.56   40.07   Sp2
-3.52   40.19   Sp3
-6.29   40.93   Sp3
-6.77   40.12   Sp3
-7.11   40.77   Sp4
-5.81   40.88   Sp4
-5.27   40.68   Sp4
-6.31   40.34   Sp4
-6.13   40.32   Sp4
-6.73   40.99   Sp4
-5.32   40.71   Sp4
-6.17   40.97   Sp4
-4.77   40.92   Sp4
-6.45   40.58   Sp5
-5.54   40.39   Sp5
-6.56   40.66   Sp5
-5.27   40.37   Sp5
```

Comment: This is probably impossible to answer without the data. Please include enough in your question to make it reproducible (use `dput`)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the prompt reply. Find now edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you are iterating through every single value of your *Species* column and not *Species* as a whole group and you pass one point of *Lat* and *Long*, so one row is being passed in `for` loop.

Hence, consider `by` to slice your data frame by the *Species* factor, iteratively passing every sliced data frame into a function. Not shown below but `by` can return a named list of objects equal to the groupings of factor(s) here being *Species*:

```
by(data, data$Species, FUN = function(df) {
  pdf(file=paste0("map ", df$Species[[1]],".pdf"), onefile=FALSE)
  plot(disaggregate(crop(elevation,newextent), 1, method="bilinear"), col = land.pal, legend=FALSE)  
  points(df$Lat, df$Long, col="black")
  dev.off()
})
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help; `by` is an often underused but very useful base R function.